# Variadic template unpacking arguments in typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, hypodermic

Given the following C++ `typedef` expression

```
template <bool> struct BoolType : std::true_type {};

template <> struct BoolType< false > : std::false_type {};

typedef BoolType< ArgResolver< Arg1 >::IsResolvable::value && ArgResolver< Arg2 >::IsResolvable::value > IsSignatureRecognized;
```

I was asking myself if it could be done with a variadic template. The code comes from [Hypodermic](https://github.com/ybainier/Hypodermic) IoC container. How can I unpack them while retaining the `&&` check between each of them?

Comment: You should try the new version of Hypodermic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write up an `and_` metafunction like this:

```
    template <class ... Bools>
    struct and_;

    template <class Bool, class ... Bools>
    struct and_<Bool, Bools...> : std::conditional<
        Bool::value, and_<Bools...>, std::false_type>::type{};

    template <>
    struct and_<> : std::true_type{};
```

I haven't tested this so there may be a couple of typos, but I hope you get the idea.

Then you use it like this:

```
    typedef and_<typename ArgResolver<Args>::IsResolvable...> IsSignatureRecognized;
```

The way it works is fairly simple, we have the generic class `template <class...> and_` which accepts any number of types. The first specialization checks the first argument in the pack, if it's false there's no need to continue since the whole `and_` will be false.  If it's true then we continue checking the rest of the parameters.  Once there are no more parameters left, the specialization with no parameters simply returns true.

Here's an example:

```
and_<t, t, f, t>::value
gives conditional<t::value, and_<t, f, t>, f>::type
```

Because the condition is true, `type` evaluates to the second parameter `and_<t, f, t>`.  Similarly for the next parameter, we get to:

```
and_<f, t>::value
gives conditional<f::value, and_<t>, f>::type
```

Now the condition is false so `type` evaluates to the third parameter `f` and we are done instantiating templates and `::value` gives us `false`.

If all the parameters are true you will eventually reach `and_<>` which we specialized to be `std::true_type` so that `::value` gives us `true`.

I hope that helps clarify how this code works.

Comment: it works! Could you just explain the code? I'm a newbie and I'm still learning variadic templates, so I didn't really understood what you did

Comment: Note that something very similar was added to C++17 called `std::conjunction`.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, I really appreciate it. @Simple that's really cool, do you know if Visual Studio 2015 supports it?

Answer (score 4):

In C++17, you may do:

```
using IsSignatureRecognized = BoolType<(ArgResolver<Args>::IsResolvable::value && ...)>;
```

before, you have to make an variadic '`and`' by yourself.

Comment: this is really nice, but I'm compiling on c++11. It was the first thing I tried (except for the using statement instead of typedef) but obviously it didn't compile